# Python Fast monochromatic bitmap

Tags: python, bitmap, performance

i want to implement 1024x1024 monochromatic grid , i need read data from any cell and insert rectangles with various dimensions, i have tried to make list in list ( and use it like 2d array ), what i have found is that list of booleans is slower than list of integers.... i have tried 1d list, and it was slower than 2d one, numpy is slower about 10 times that standard python list, fastest way that i have found is PIL and monochromatic bitmap used with "load" method, but i want it to run a lot faster, so i have tried to compile it with shedskin, but unfortunately there is no pil support there, do you know any way of implementing such grid faster without rewriting it to c or c++ ?

Comment: I'm surprised NumPy was slow for you. How were you using it? I would expect its slicing syntax to work very well for setting rectangles to a given value. Also, what dtypes did you test with?

Comment: Depending on your OS, you may be able to find a Python interface that talks directly to the underlying GUI being used which likely has graphics primitives available do do  everything you want.

Answer (score 2):

Raph's suggestin of using array is good, but it won't help on CPython, in fact I'd expect it to be 10-15% slower, however if you use it on PyPy (http://pypy.org/) I'd expect excellent results.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I might suggest is using Python's built-in array class (http://docs.python.org/library/array.html), with a type of 'B'. Coding will be simplest if you use one byte per pixel, but if you want to save memory, you can pack 8 to a byte, and access using your own bit manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into [Cython](http://cython.org/) which translates the Python into C that is readily compiled (or compiled for you if you use distutils). Just compiling your code in Cython will make it faster for something like this, but you can get much greater speed-ups by adding a few cdef statements. If you [use it with Numpy](http://wiki.cython.org/tutorials/numpy), then you can quickly access Numpy arrays. The speed-up can be quite large by using Cython in this manner. However, it would easier to help you if you provided some example code.